# Scala: classOf a generic

Tags: json, scala, class, generics

I want to load & parse a JSON file with scala 2.11.8, in a generic way, like this:

```
private val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

def loadFile[T](path: Path): Try[T] = Try(
  objectMapper.readValue(Files.readAllBytes(path), classOf[T])
)
```

Then the goal is to call the loadFile method with only the expected return type.

However this returns me:

```
class type required but T found
```

By googling, I found references to erasures, manifests, ClassTag but nothing works. What is the correct solution?

Comment: could you please elaborate your question ?

Comment: `T` is not a class, it is a placeholder, erased at runtime. So you cannot call `classOf[T]`. You could add an implicit parameter `clazz: Class[T]`. Also, maybe take a look at Scala JSON libraries instead of Jackson. They have better support for typesafe JSON.

Answer (score 4):

The generic type gets erased, so you need a `ClassTag` to make it work. This is how you can use them:

```
def loadFile[T: ClassTag](path: Path): Try[T] = Try(
  objectMapper.readValue(
    Files.readAllBytes(path),
    implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
)
```

(For some reason, `runtimeClass` doesn't have the generic type, so you need the cast.)